# Como reconhecer o tipo de dado inserido - C

Tags: c, entrada-de-dados

Estou fazendo um programa onde o usuário pode cadastrar, buscar e remover clientes. Para inserir ele digita "inserir [nome do cliente]"  e um código é gerado automaticamente. Estou com um problema na função de busca. Atualmente o usuário tem que digitar: "buscar x y" onde x é um int q identifica se a busca será feita pelo código ou nome do cliente e y é o valor correspondente. Eu queria fazer isso sem pedir ao usuário para especificar o tipo de busca. Tem alguma forma de receber o dado e depois verificar se eu recebi um inteiro ou uma string?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar a função isdigit, terá de percorrer toda a entrada com ela, se colocar o código fica mais fácil, mas segue um exemplo tirado da ajuda do watcom c.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

    //Aqui você não necessita por um vetor, imagine que seja o texto que 
     você está armazenando

char chars[] = {
    'A',
    '5',
    '$'
};
#define SIZE sizeof( chars ) / sizeof( char )
int main()
{
    int   i;

    //Faça um for percorrendo a entrada caracter por caracter

    for( i = 0; i < SIZE; i++ ) {
        printf( "Char %c is %sa digit character\n",
                chars[i],
                ( isdigit( chars[i] ) ) ? "" : "not " );
                 //Verifique na função isdigit se é um numero ou não, da 
proxima vez por favor deixar o codigo
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, não coloquei o código porque como é um caso mais geral achei que não faria diferença, na próxima eu coloco.

Comment: Tudo bem, mas veja se consegue, caso o contrario só dar uma avisada aqui @Raul Boa sorte